# Have sub-domain point to different firebase project than base domain

Tags: subdomain, web-hosting, dns-hosting, firebase

I am trying to get my project domain `mypage.com` to be hosted at and point to a firebase project `A`, and also have a sub domain, `admin.mypage.com`, point to and be hosted at firebase project `B`.

I have my `mypage.com` domain registered at `domains.google.com`.

I have successfully connected `mypage.com` to project `A`, but creating a new A record with name `admin` and pointing it to the IP address within firebase project B overrides the initial A record, connecting the `mypage.com` domain to project A.
problem is that Firebase assigns the same IP address for all my projects it seems.

Is there a way for me to achieve this with google domains service?

My current DNS looks like this:[image]

Later on I tried using the CNAME record, and pointing it to project B's auto generated Firebase domain `project-b.web.app`. Will see if that works.

Comment: Can you show us your DNS configuration?

Comment: @AvivLo DNS added

Comment: Are those the actual IPs or did you replace them with the dummy ones?

Comment: Actual ones  @AvivLo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after trying all the above, the way it worked for me was using a `CNAME` record pointing to the auto-generated `firebase` domain for the project.

Looks something like this:

```
admin       CNAME       1H       my-project.firebaseapp.com
```

Answer (score 2):

This is my DNS setup on Cloudflare. Perhaps this can be a helpful example for you. I have two A records. One pointing to the production server and the other one points the staging one.

So for this setup, the URL to the production server is `knct.me` while the URL for the staging server is `staging.knct.me`. The 2 A records work without problems though `staging.knct.me` looks like it is a CNAME record of `knct.me`

The IPs in the picture are changed to random ones for security reasons.

[image]

Comment: Interesting so you dont use the @ in any A record, just the full domain name? Because the @ is how firebase tells me to set it up. I am unsure of what it does/means so I blindly follow it...maybe I will read up on it and see.

Comment: @Jousi That is just how CloudFlare displays it. They display the domain name instead of @. It's a bit confusing at first. They both mean the same thing.

Comment: Oh I see. Either way, the problem is that Firebase assigns the same IP address for all my projects it seems, so I dont think this is going to work.
I did read about how the different types work and a solution might in the end be the CNAME that will point to one of the Firebase generated project B domains. I have added the admin.mypage.com CNAME record which now points to projectB.web.app. Will see what happens.

Comment: @Jousi let us know.